# How to place a Configuration Source to a certain Configuration Section to avoid key conflicts?

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core, .net-standard

I have two configuration files:

`users.json`:

```
{
  "Alice" : { "Email": "alice@example.com" },
  "Bob" : { "Email": "bob@example.com" }
}
```

and `connections.json`

```
{
  "Database" : { "ConnectionString": "..." },
  "Gateway" : { "Url": "http://..." }
}
```

And I'm trying to compose a single configuration root:

```
var cfg = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("users.json")
    .AddJsonFile("connections.json")
    .Build();
```

Obviously, I need to place each configuration source into it's section: `Users` and `Connections` - to avoid conflicts. Some kind of a prefixing wrapper can do the job, but I don't want to implement my own.

How would you handle this situation if you're not able to modify configuration file structure (in real project there's a reason for that)?

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to [JsonConfigurationFileParser](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Config.Json/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs) and [JsonConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Config.Json/JsonConfigurationProvider.cs) classes implementation looks like you only may to write own `FileConfigurationProvider` implementation.

---

As a workaround you may do the following (step by step):

- => read configurations per file
- => then get result as a collection of KeyValuePair items
- => then append some custom prefix to each key name (in your case based on file name)
- => merging: append final collection as MemoryCollection source to root configuration

The following code is the idea implementation and may need modification before using in prod:

```
public static class ConfigurationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddJsonFileWithPrefix(this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, string fileName, string prefix) 
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            // you may need to set up base path again here
            // .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile(fileName).Build();

        var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        foreach(var pair in config.AsEnumerable())
        {
            result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>($"{prefix}:{pair.Key}", pair.Value));
        }

        return configurationBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(result);
    }
}
```

then you may create configuration root as:

```
var cfg = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFileWithPrefix("users.json", "users")
    .AddJsonFileWithPrefix("connections.json", "connections")
    .Build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your sample. Just few problems in case you're going to improve it: 1) reload mechanism will not work; 2) it is possible to make it more general (to work not only with json)

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your json files to reflect sections:

users.json:

```
{
    "Users": {
        "Alice" : { "Email": "alice@example.com" },
        "Bob" : { "Email": "bob@example.com" }
    }
}
```

and connections.json

```
{
    "Connections": {
        "Database" : { "ConnectionString": "..." },
        "Gateway" : { "Url": "http://..." }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's easy to argue against configuration de-normalization in general, but in my case it is simply not an option to modify this files